# Personal Hotspot not staying Connected

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, tethering

I'm not sure if I have an issue or if what I am seeing is by Apple-design.  I have an iPad Pro (11.4) that I have the Personal Hotspot switched on.

1. My iPad Pro is active and screen on.
2. I connect my iPhoneX (11.4) to the iPad Hotspot.
3. Everything works fine.
4. I sat working on laptop and then the iPhone X and iPad screen locked.  After X minutes I then unlock iPhone to check email etc..
5. The iPhone X has disconnected from the hotspot and is back to using the cellular plan on my iPhone.  If I go to Settings -> Wi-Fi then my iPad is not listed.
6. To make the hotspot reconnect I have to go back to my iPad and toggle the Personal HotSpot switch (On -> Off -> On).

Is this by design or not?  Should the iPhone remain connected if the devices screen lock?

Comment: Been getting the same issue but only since 11.3/11.4. Before that didn't have this "feature". Also getting a lot of general hotspot connection issues at the same time necessitating regular reboots or airplane mode switches to kick it into life.

Answer (score 11):

After further experimentation I found that if I create a Bluetooth connection (pair) between iPhone/iPad it stays connected throughout screen locks etc.

Comment: Confirmed this also works with two Iphones

Comment: I’m impressed with this ingenious design and ux by Apple.

Answer (score 5):

**Finally a working solution!**

Turn off Auto-Lock on your iPhone/iPad. If you set Auto-Lock to "Never", the Personal Hotspot will stay active. Even with screen locked for hours.

No more disconnects after 1 to 5 minutes.

Comment: This absolutely works! Thank you! The auto-lock must disable the hotspot as a power-saving feature.

Comment: Would be cool to create a shortcut automation (when plugged and at home -> disable auto-lock) sadly you cannot control auto-lock with shortcut.

Comment: It's a solution, I suppose, but it doesn't seem to be the RIGHT solution. Why should the screen-dimming function govern hotspot duration? Ideally you'd want the hotspot connection on for as long as you want to be connected, while still allowing screen-dimming to save battery.

Comment: I thought this was it but 15 or so minutes later, the connection failed again and when I try to reconnect, I get ”failed to create remote hotspot” or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's partially by design. Whenever my son wants to connect to my Personal hotspot, I have to open the Personal Hotspot screen, even if it's already on and he's got the network/password saved away. But, I don't have to toggle it off/on.

Also, disconnecting from a hotspot is automatic when the client device sleeps.

Comment: its such a nightmare if you connect a router to the tether

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with 2 iPhones. It appeared that iOS 12 is saving power by disabling Hotspot broadcast then the signal disappears afterwards.

To fix this Go to iPhone setting -> 'Battery health' and disable the battery saving mode.
You find a small link under 'Peak Performance Capability', the option once disabled disappears and cannot be enabled again.

Comment: you can re enable it again

Comment: How do you re-enable the link?

Answer (score 1):

I was annoyed by this *battery-saving feature* of iPhone tethering for over a year. What it normally does is to drop the connection when the traffic was not intensive enough, for example downloading a huge file vs. watching YouTube video with buffering.

After searching around, I found the following methods that actually work!

- [Tethering over a USB](https://support.speedify.com/article/426-connect-pc-tethered-iphone-usb)
- [Disable Auto-Lock](https://www.imore.com/how-change-auto-lock-your-iphone-and-ipad), and leave the screen to the **hotspot setting page**.
- Play Spotify in the background on PC (or whatever device that's using the hotspot).

Answer (score 0):

iPhone is trying to save battery when there is no data being transmitted to the connected device, for a given duration, by switch off the hotspot. If you live stream any video in youtube from your connected device, you could get around this problem.